# Can't read data from Firestore using my Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a simple function to learn how to read data from my firestore. The **index.js** file looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// GET
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('users').doc('vUuMvkP03J2hMryAm9ok').get().then(snapshot => {
        response.send(snapshot.username);
    }).catch(reason => {
        response.send(reason);
    });
});

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In the `GET` request, I'm trying to read the document stored under `users` collection, and send back the `username` field. My database looks like this:

[image]

When I go to my function's URL, I get an empty page with nothing on it. No sensible errors either. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can access username in the data property of the snapshot `snapshot.data().username`

Answer (score 2):

The firestore response's data is in `snapshot.data()` If you add that to your callback, you should be good

```
response.send(snapshot.data().username);
```

There are other properties on the snapshot like `snapshot.id` which would give you `vUuMvkP03J2hMryAm9ok` in your example.